# In a matrix, find the mean of column 4 values associated with 20th to 30th percentile values in column 1

Tags: r, matrix, aggregate, mean

Essentially, I want to build a spider plot for sensitivity analysis. I want to split my data into 10 tranches, and find the mean result value (in column 4) for each tranche. The tranches should be selected based on the 10th, 20th, 30th, 40th, etc. percentiles for the data in each of the variable columns. I got this to work, but I'm thinking that there must be a much easier way to do it.

My code:

```
##Make some data and put it into a matrix.

c <- 1000
v1 <- rnorm (c, 100, 15)
v2 <- rnorm (c, 80, 10)
v3 <- rnorm (c, 50, 5)
r1 <- ((v1*v2^2)/v3)
data <- cbind (v1,v2)
data <- cbind (data, v3)
data <- cbind (data, r1)

##Sort matrix by first column.
data <- as.matrix(data[order(data[,1]),])

##Find mean of column 4 values corresponding to the smallest 10% (and 20%, and 30%,     etc.) of column 1 values.
a1 <- mean (data[1:(c/10),4])
a2 <- mean (data[(c/10):(2*c/10),4])
a3 <- mean (data[(2*c/10):(3*c/10),4])
a4 <- mean (data[(3*c/10):(4*c/10),4])
a5 <- mean (data[(4*c/10):(5*c/10),4])
a6 <- mean (data[(5*c/10):(6*c/10),4])
a7 <- mean (data[(6*c/10):(7*c/10),4])
a8 <- mean (data[(7*c/10):(8*c/10),4])
a9 <- mean (data[(8*c/10):(9*c/10),4])
a10 <- mean (data[(9*c/10):c,4])

##Combine into a vector.
a <- as.vector(c(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10))

##Repeat for data sorted by columns 2 and 3 respectively.
data <- as.matrix(data[order(data[,2]),])

a1 <- mean (data[1:(c/10),4])
a2 <- mean (data[(c/10):(2*c/10),4])
a3 <- mean (data[(2*c/10):(3*c/10),4])
a4 <- mean (data[(3*c/10):(4*c/10),4])
a5 <- mean (data[(4*c/10):(5*c/10),4])
a6 <- mean (data[(5*c/10):(6*c/10),4])
a7 <- mean (data[(6*c/10):(7*c/10),4])
a8 <- mean (data[(7*c/10):(8*c/10),4])
a9 <- mean (data[(8*c/10):(9*c/10),4])
a10 <- mean (data[(9*c/10):c,4])

b <- as.vector(c(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10))

data <- as.matrix(data[order(data[,3]),])

a1 <- mean (data[1:(c/10),4])
a2 <- mean (data[(c/10):(2*c/10),4])
a3 <- mean (data[(2*c/10):(3*c/10),4])
a4 <- mean (data[(3*c/10):(4*c/10),4])
a5 <- mean (data[(4*c/10):(5*c/10),4])
a6 <- mean (data[(5*c/10):(6*c/10),4])
a7 <- mean (data[(6*c/10):(7*c/10),4])
a8 <- mean (data[(7*c/10):(8*c/10),4])
a9 <- mean (data[(8*c/10):(9*c/10),4])
a10 <- mean (data[(9*c/10):c,4])

d <- as.vector(c(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10))

##Make a pretty chart
plot (a, type = "o", col = "red") 
lines (b, type = "o", col = "blue") 
lines (d, type = "o", col = "green")
```

Comment: +1 for providing a working example of what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that does the same thing, but a more compactly and idiomatically for R.

```
n <- 1000
# changed from c to n since you use c again later as something else
v1 <- rnorm (n, 100, 15)
v2 <- rnorm (n, 80, 10)
v3 <- rnorm (n, 50, 5)
r1 <- ((v1*v2^2)/v3)

DF <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3, r1)
# A data.frame seems like it would be a better fit for this

library("Hmisc")
# The Hmisc package has a function which splits in to quantiles, so use it
DF <- transform(DF, 
                v1.decile = cut2(v1, g=10),
                v2.decile = cut2(v2, g=10),
                v3.decile = cut2(v3, g=10))
# add three new variables to the data frame which indicate which decile each
# value belongs to, for each of v1, v2, and v3
a <- aggregate(DF$r1, list(DF$v1.decile), mean)$x
# why add the new variables? because aggregate can perform an operation on
# groups of one variable defined by the value of another variable
b <- aggregate(DF$r1, list(DF$v2.decile), mean)$x
c <- aggregate(DF$r1, list(DF$v3.decile), mean)$x
```

Then you can make the plot like you did before.

---

EDIT:

Ananda Mahto's answer pointed out the function version of the aggregate function which I  had forgotten about.  You could write the `aggregate` lines more clearly as

```
a <- aggregate(r1 ~ v1.decile, DF, mean)$r1
b <- aggregate(r1 ~ v2.decile, DF, mean)$r1
c <- aggregate(r1 ~ v3.decile, DF, mean)$r1
```

Comment: Great job bringing together all the ideas: transform(), cut2(), aggregate().

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar conceptually to Brian Diggs's answer but doesn't depend on your input being a `data.frame` nor on loading any packages. It also introduces `matplot`, which will give you your plot without having to plot each column one at a time.

Here's your data:

```
set.seed(1) # make it reproducible 
n <- 1000
v1 <- rnorm (c, 100, 15)
v2 <- rnorm (c, 80, 10)
v3 <- rnorm (c, 50, 5)
r1 <- ((v1*v2^2)/v3)
data <- cbind (v1, v2, v3, r1)
rm(v1, v2, v3, r1) # Cleanup

head(data)
#             v1       v2       v3        r1
# [1,]  90.60319 95.11781 54.59489 15014.651
# [2,] 102.75465 83.89843 53.91068 13416.349
# [3,]  87.46557 73.78759 50.37282  9453.824
# [4,] 123.92921 57.85300 40.05324 10355.899
# [5,] 104.94262 91.24931 53.09913 16455.977
# [6,]  87.69297 79.55066 49.71936 11161.612
```

We'll use `sapply` to perform our aggregation. This will result in a matrix that we can plot easily.

```
myAggVars <- c("v1", "v2", "v3")
temp <- sapply(myAggVars, function(x) {
  aggregate(r1 ~ cut(get(x), quantile(get(x), probs = seq(0, 1, .1)), 
                     include.lowest = TRUE), data, mean)[[2]]
})
temp
#              v1        v2        v3
#  [1,]  9453.824 10355.899 10355.899
#  [2,] 11161.612  9453.824 20834.485
#  [3,] 15014.651 11161.612 17755.902
#  [4,] 13528.961 13896.830 13896.830
#  [5,] 13416.349 13416.349 11161.612
#  [6,] 16455.977 13528.961  9453.824
#  [7,] 13896.830 17755.902 13528.961
#  [8,] 17755.902 20834.485 16455.977
#  [9,] 20834.485 16455.977 13416.349
# [10,] 10355.899 15014.651 15014.651
```

Here's the plotting step:

```
matplot(temp, type = "o", pch = 1)
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Nice use of `sapply` to loop through all the variables and dynamically create the splitting variable. And `matplot` does a much better job of plotting, then.

Comment: @BrianDiggs, credit goes to you for putting all the pieces together to begin with!